# Interactive Brokers' Python API: "not connected" error on mistaken parameters and otherwise

Tags: python, ibpy

I'm working on an application to automate some trades via Interactive Brokers' Python API.

So far I have no trouble getting a simple example trade accepted:

```py
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "GOOG"
contract.secType = "OPT"
contract.exchange = "BOX"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20191018"
contract.strike = 1230
contract.right = "C"
contract.multiplier = "100"

app.simplePlaceOid = 51

order = Order()
order.action = "BUY"
order.orderType = "LMT"
order.totalQuantity = 1
order.lmtPrice = 24.60
app.placeOrder(app.simplePlaceOid, contract, order)
```

But I need to support option spread orders with multiple legs.

I realized I was missing the **conId** member when setting up legs of the trade, and this was giving me an unhelpful **504 You are not connected** error.

So I tried to run examples of the routine to get the contract IDs, even the example from the documentation:

```py
self.reqMatchingSymbols(211, "IB")
```

... and I get a similar **you are not connected** error.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: You're not connected.  Click the DATA text in TWS and you can see if you're connected.  Note that any errors in your code can make TWS disconnect you.  Check your API log files (make sure to always have these turned on).

Comment: Yes, I was connected. I looked at the log and it was connected all the way up to the placeOrder call.